# Android offline map api

Tags: android, dictionary, routes, offline

i want to develop android app for routing and navigation
i'm looking for an api for map routing(shortest and fastest route calculation) with offline map and routing support 
Any ideas and experience on that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) is solution for you.

(online routing with [osmbonuspack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1) or offline with osmdroid + GraphHopper or just with [GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.3/docs/android/index.md))

osmdroid is a (almost) full/free replacement for Android's MapView (v1 API) class. It also includes a modular tile provider system with support for numerous online and offline tile sources and overlay support with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location, and drawing shapes.

Comment: thanks for reply .does osmdroid  able to handle routing functions? I think it is not possible use  routing functions  with tile source

Comment: Yes, you can use online routing with [osmbonuspack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1) or offline with osmdroid + GraphHopper or just with [GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.3/docs/android/index.md)

Comment: how can i prepare offline map for grophHopper ? in what format?

Comment: [Here (section "Maps")](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.3/docs/android/index.md) is step by step howto.

Comment: excuse me  . i can't understand step 1 and 2  . in step 1 the link that represented  offer  3 format .osm.pbf .shp.zip  .osm.bz2  which one i must download  ?   thanks for your help  i really appreciate your help

Comment: The .osm.pbf data format is the common format for the exchange of raw OpenStreetMap data.